# SDL: how to get the mouse motion while the left mouse button is down using case statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement, mouseevent, sdl-2

I am currently working with SDL2 and am fairly new to it. I am trying to use case statments to get the mouse motion coordinates only while the left mouse button is pressed down.

In the end, I need to be able to click on a object and find how much the mouse is dragged from that selected object.

So far I have been able to get the mouse press and the mouse motion working separately, but not at the same time.

Here is my code for the mouse press event:

```
void SDL::OnEvent(SDL_Event *_event)
{
Mallet mallet;

switch (_event->type)
{
case SDL_QUIT:
    m_running = false;
    break;

default:
    break;


case SDL_KEYUP:
    switch (_event->key.keysym.sym)
    {
    case SDLK_SPACE:
        if(m_playerTurn == 1)
            m_playerTurn = 2;
        else
            m_playerTurn = 1;

        std::cout<<"player turn = "<<m_playerTurn<<std::endl;
        break;

    }


case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

    switch(_event->button.button)
    {
    case SDL_BUTTON_LEFT:
        int x = _event->button.x;
        int y = _event->button.y;

        if(m_playerTurn == 1)
        {
            bool collision = checkCollision(x, y, m_player1->getTeamMallets(), mallet);
            if(collision)
                std::cout<<"collision with P1"<<std::endl;
        }

        if(m_playerTurn == 2)
        {
            bool collision = checkCollision(x, y, m_player2->getTeamMallets(), mallet);
            if(collision)
                std::cout<<"collision with P2"<<std::endl;
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone help.

Many thanks in advance.

Will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on `SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` set variable click = true ans save x,y  coordinates,
on `SDL_MOUSEMOTION` check if click == true and update x,y coordinates,
on `SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP` set click = false and calculate distance.

http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/17_mouse_events/index.php

Comment: Great thankyou very much. Seems so simple when you explain it like that. Dont know why i didnt think of it :)